# No brightness control on Asus 75 laptop

Tags: nvidia, backlight

How can I get the brightness on my ASUS G75 laptop to work in Ubuntu  12.10 alpha?

On my MacBook Pro, there used to be an nvidia-bl-dkms module. On my Dell XPS 15z, it worked out of the box. Now I am a little bit stumped and need help.

I've got the nvidia-current 304.43 drivers installed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got brightness control to basically (but not perfectly) work on my ASUS G75VW-DH72 by following these steps:

1. Add the line `Option "registryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"` in the appropriate Device section of the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file.
2. Do `sudo pico /etc/default/grub` and add `acpi_osi=Linux and acpi_backlight=vendor` to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT variable.  Press Ctrl+O to save.
3. Run `sudo update-grub` to rebuild `grub.cfg`.
4. Reboot.

It's not working perfectly for me yet; I have to press the backlight hotkey twice before it registers, and then when it registers it increments the brightness by 2 instead of by 1, so I only have 6 accessible brightnesses.  You can do better by directly writing integers into `/sys/class/backlight/asus-nb-wmi/brightness`.  If you find solutions to those problems, *please* let me know!

The nvidiabl thing did not work for me at all when I tried it.

This page is a useful resource:
http://www.linlap.com/asus_g75vw