# acpi_listen only detects every other backlight hotkey press

Tags: brightness, asus, acpi, backlight

I am trying to get the LCD backlight brightness control to work properly on my new ASUS G75VW-DH72 laptop in Ubuntu 12.10.  I got it to mostly work by following the [instructions that I wrote here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182250/no-brightness-control-on-asus-75-laptop/224758#224758) (acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor, EnableBrightnessControl=1).  However, there are still two issues:

The main issue is that I have to press the hotkey (fn+F5 or fn+F6) TWICE before there is any effect on the brightness, or any output in the `acpi_listen` command.  So if I run `acpi_listen` and press fn+F6 **six** times, the output only has **three** lines:

```
video LCDD 00000086 00000000
video LCDD 00000086 00000000
video LCDD 00000086 00000000
```

What causes this?  How can I fix it?  This behavior doesn't happen in Windows.

(Also, I noticed that the brightness is incrementing/decrementing in steps of 2 instead of 1, unless I happen to have a menu open.  Any advice on that is welcome.)

Answer (score 0):

I was do the same as above. Then I had to Text my g75VW and closed the lid.

I come back after a while then I opened the lid and then the backlight was working with F5/F6 as it should be…

Only the onscreen display not showing…

I tried again with lid closing and after a while open it and it still working..

Hope it's helps.

Comment: Interesting.  So it's working for you now?  Can you run acpi_listen and tell me what you get when your press the Fn+F5 four times followed by Fn+F6 four times?  Are you using the nvidia proprietary driver or nouveau  (`lsmod | grep nou`)?